# Differentiation what to do of the ''a'' nothing is mentioned about it in question

Tags: calculus

[image]

Please help..  what to do of the ''a'' nothing is mentioned about it in question

Comment: $a$ is probably a constant.

Comment: $a$ is a constant. $K$ and $r$ are noted to be "positive" constants, which is why they are specified while $a$ is ignored. $a$ could be positive or negative.

Comment: There is a $r$: $f(N) = r(aN-N^2)...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(N)=r(aN-N^2)\left(1-\frac{N}{k}\right)$$
using rules
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
and $$(cf)'=cf'$$
we have
$$f'(N)=r\left((aN-N^2)'(1-\frac{N}{k})+(aN-N^2)\left(1-\frac{N}{k}\right)'\right)$$
$$f'(N)=r\left((a-2N)(1-\frac{N}{k})-\frac{1}{k}(aN-N^2)\right)$$
$$f'(N)=r\left((a-2N)(1-\frac{N}{k})-\frac{1}{k}(aN-N^2)\right)$$
$$f'(N)=\frac{r}{k}((a-2N)(k-N)-(aN-N^2))$$
$$f'(N)=\frac{r}{k}(ak-2aN-2kN+3N^2)$$